# Position and Alternatives of Naming Java loop control variable in `for(){}` loops

Tags: java, loops, variables, syntax, increment

### Loop Control Variable Naming and Assignment Options (header vs. assignment in body of loop)

In short, a) is the control variable (i.e., 'counter') in a *for loop* usually named `i` out of convention and/or syntax, b) and is it advisable that one change the name *inside* the loop header or should one rather make an assignment inside the loop body? To make this question clear, I have presented two simple code blocks below for illustration, one with `i` and the other without. N.B., the assignment within the loop body of the first block.

```java
// maintain use of i
class Coffee {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int cupsOfCoffee = 1;
    

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      i = cupsOfCoffee;
      cupsOfCoffee++;
      System.out.println("Molly drinks cup of coffee #" + i);
    }   
  }
}
```

Or this one, eliminating `i`:

```java
// use cupsOfCoffee as control variable
class Coffee {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
  
    for (int cupsOfCoffee = 1; cupsOfCoffee <= 100; cupsOfCoffee++) {
      
      System.out.println("Molly drinks cup of coffee #" + cupsOfCoffee);
      
    }    
  }
}
```

### Expansion of Question

Traditionally we use `i` as the control variable in initialization, the boolean expression, and increments in the header of loop (`for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)`). Suppose, I am counting the cups of coffee (`cupsOfCoffee`) that Molly drinks. Is the first code block, leaving `i` in the loop header and declaring `i = cupsOfCoffee` preferred syntactically and/or by convention, or is the second method acceptable? The goal of this question is to make sure my code is stylistically, conventionally, and syntactically correct.

Comment: Have you run your two bits of code? What did they do?

Comment: But to answer your question: if the value of your loop variable represents cups of cofefe, it should be named `cupsOfCoffee`.

Comment: I think there is no problem to use a proper name instead of the conventional `i`. But I noticed that your first example is wrong, as it will print always 1, and never end.

Comment: First one will always print #1. 
And if we go back to the things, I always prefer simplicity and readability. 
However, what you do with first code block is: Taking money from left pocket and putting to the right pocket, then taking money from your right pocket and giving money to the cashier.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include `cupsOfCoffee++;` which should be after the print statement, but it is before in my example... i apologize for the typo. When run, both codes yield same result and increment up to 100 cupsOfCoffee. All comments above are helpful. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it is perfectly acceptable to use variables other than i or j in loops. Programming is about writing understandable code, so a variable called ´cupsOfCoffee´ is very self-explanatory. It could thus also be useful for developers, working on the project you are working on.